# How is this object being created?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the implementation of [particle.js](http://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso) and in the codepen he sets the configurations for the effect. But I don't understand what exactly is happening, or where it is being called so the configurations take effect.

My guess is that in the *particle.js* file a particleJS object is created which takes two values, but I can't find where this object is created.

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
```

[link to the codepen](http://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso)

Comment: Short answer - [here](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js#L1477)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.particlesJS = function(tag_id, params){` is in http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/assets/_build/js/lib/particles.js

Comment: Don't know how I missed it. After not finding it I thought there would another way to define the object which I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.particlesJS = function(tag_id, params){
```

https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js#L1477